# Use jQuery to set select box value to first option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dynamically populating a select box with options.  When I do this, I want the value of the select box to be the value of the first option (a 'default option', if you like). Sounds really simple, but I just can't get it to work.

```
var myElement = $('select[name="myName"]');
```

.... tried the following three variations

```
// myElement.find('option').first().prop('selected', 'selected');
// myElement.val(myElement.find('options').first().val());
myElement.prop('selectedIndex', 0);
```

...but the following line gives a blank alert

```
alert(myElement.val());
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: How are you populating the options? Could you create a JSFiddle example?

Comment: the only reason I'm seeing is the first option has a value blank if after the corrections also you are getting blank as the result

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**options** should be **option**

```
myElement.find('option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true);
```

You can use the `eq` selector on the option to select the first option.

If you know the value of the first option. Then you could simply do

```
myElemeent.val('first value') // Which selects the option by default
```

The 2nd case you tried should work, unless you are not calling at the right point . i.e; waiting for the ajax response to be completed.

Try calling that inside the `done` or the `success` (deprecated) handler

Comment: thanks Sushanth - you were right about me not waiting for the ajax to complete.

Comment: @Sushanth-- Would this then trigger any .change() watchers associated to the select in question?

Answer (score 6):

You almost got it, drop the 's' in 'options':

```
myElement.val(myElement.find('option').first().val());
```

**[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZXqfW/)**

Comment: @KimPrince why? look at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZXqfW/) it works.. I've set "selected" on the last option then using this code reverted to the first option

Comment: Thanks Yotam, you are right but I was not waiting for the ajax call to complete.  see Sushanth's response...

Answer (score 5):

You could also use next code:

```
myElement[0].selectedIndex = 0;
```

This get's the Dom element (not jQuery object), works with vanilla Javascript and uses it to set the first option as the selected one based on it's index.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be sure that your option has a value and is not a placeholder you can do:

```
$('select option').filter( function (index, option) {
  return option.attributes.value
}).val()
```

That way you'll check if the HTML node has attribute `value` and is not empty.